# Создание объектов одного класса с независимыми полями

Tags: python, python-3.x

Изучая Python натолкнулся вот на такой казус:

```
class Vrm:
    arr = []

    def addArr(self, temp):
        self.arr.append(temp)

a = Vrm()
b = Vrm()

a.addArr(2)

print(b.arr[0]) #Тут будет результат 2
```

То есть, по-идее я считал, что должна быть ошибка, ведь для объекта b еще не добавлено данных данных, только для объекта "а". Но получается, что при создании нового объекта b, поле класса arr (которое является листом), содержит ссылку на уже созданный ранее массив. Этот массив был создан, при создании объекта "а". Получается, что у этих двух объектов одно поле arr на двоих. А как сделать, чтобы у них было свое персональное поле arr?
P.S. Посмотрел в интернете, но не могу сообразить как это правильно сделать.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

То, что вы делает - это свойство класса. Чтобы было динамическое свойство объекта,  его надо и создавать через self

```
class Vrm:
    def __init__(self):
        self.arr = []

    def addArr(self, temp):
        self.arr.append(temp)

a = Vrm()
b = Vrm()

a.addArr(2)

print(a.arr)      # [2]
print(b.arr[0])   # IndexError: list index out of range on line 14
```

Comment: * свойство самого класса, а не объекта

Comment: Спасибо. Совсем забыл, что через конструктор можно делать динамические поля. Не знал, что этот способ позволяет создавать отдельные листы. Еще раз спасибо ).

Comment: спасибо, не вспомнил формулировку :)